# Proof that any other 2 argument logic function other than NAND or NOR is not functionally complete

Tags: logic

Any tips how to prove the title?
I know how to show that NAND and NOR are functionally complete, but how do you prove reverse for any other 2 argument logic function?

Comment: See [Adequate set of connectives](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~lila/logic/adequate.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You could, boringly, examine all sixteen possible truth-functions of two variables in turn, and argue by elimination. But here's how to speed things up considerably, in three steps

1. Argue that the value of  $A \circ B$ for $A$ and $B$ both **T** has to be **F** if the set of connectives containing just $\circ$ by itself is to be functionally 
   complete (a.k.a. expressively adequate). [Why? Well suppose $A \circ B$ were also **T** when $A$ and $B$ both are: could you ever express negation using $\circ$ ?]
2. Argue that the value of  $A \circ B$ for $A$ and $B$ both **F** has to be **T** [Why? A dual argument, flipping **F**'s and **T**'s ...]
3. So that means there are only four possible candidates for the complete truth-table for an expressive adequate $\circ$, namely NAND, NOR and two others. Argue that the other two can't possibly be expressively adequate connectives [Why? Trivial when you note what these other two are!]

And you are done ...